# c# itextsharp add item to list field

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, itext

I have a number of fields inside a PDF, these fields are list fields. In my application I'm iterating over a number of object and on each object, adding an item to the associated form field... but it's not working.

I'm not sure how you go about adding a new list item to a PDF list field using iTextSharp.

I have even tried having the fields as multi-line textboxes, and then adding a new row using Environment.NewLine when setting the value. But this didn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this, the pdf fields were 'locked' therefore I couldn't set the value on them. Unlocking them worked fine.